# How to configure Texmaker to work on Mac with MacTeX?

Tags: texmaker, mac, mactex

I installed [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) for mac and download [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/) and installed this `.zip`:

[image]

1. I couldn't find the files in `/usr/` or `/bin/`.
2. What are the preferences I should enter in these cells? Please give me the full paths

[image]

Comment: I've tided up the comments here, which established that the link given does not lead to the installation of TeX Live (the 'business end' of MacTeX) at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you have, while saying MacTeX 2011, is actually pointing to the download for a part of MacTeX 2012 which works only with a DVD containing 'vanilla' TeX Live. This should get fixed on the website: I will report it. However, what you want is the latest MacTeX. That's always available from the link http://www.tug.org/mactex/ (note: no year), and on that page you want http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/MacTeX.pkg, which is the full Mac installer, about 2 Gb.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this might help. Here are the settings of the automatically set preferences of TeXmaker 3.5.2 on Mac OS 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

[Settings](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5462704/TexMakerSettings.ini) file as suggested in the comments by @texenthusiast

### Basic

LaTeX: `"/usr/texbin/latex" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
pdfLaTeX: `"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

XeLaTeX: `"/usr/texbin/xelatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

Latexmk: `"/usr/texbin/latexmk" -e "$pdflatex=q/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode/" -pdf %.tex`

### Misc.

Bib(la)tex: `"/usr/texbin/bibtex" %.aux`
Makeindex: `"/usr/texbin/makeindex" %.idx`

dvips: `"/usr/texbin/dvips" -o %.ps %.dvi`
Dvipdfm: `"/usr/texbin/dvipdfm" %.dvi`
ps2pdf: `"/usr/local/bin/ps2pdf" %.ps`

metapost: `"/usr/texbin/mpost" --interaction nonstopmode`
Asymptote: `/usr/bin/asy %.asy`

ghostscript: `/usr/local/bin/gs`

R Sweave: `R CMD Sweave %.Rnw`

[image: Settings Screenshot]

Comment: You could add the contents of the various boxes in clear text

Comment: @IceQueeny, you can also share your `Texmaker` settings file `Save a copy of Setting file` in `Options` menu. Anyone can pick the commandline options from them.

Comment: that would have been easier.. didn't know that yet. But the question is also if that helps at all.. seems like there is some other problem..

Answer (score 1):

Note that the path would be different for the new version of MacTex since 2021: http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html

To quote:
MacTeX writes a symbolic link /Library/TeX/texbin which indirectly points to the TeX Live binary directory. Configure your GUI programs to use this link. The GUI programs we supply should automatically configure themselves. On older systems, you may have seen the link /usr/texbin which did the same thing. When Apple produced El Capitan, they modified the system so users could no longer write directly to the /usr directory and this rule remains in effect today. Therefore we replaced /usr/texbin with /Library/TeX/texbin.