# How to configure Texmaker with Mactex?

Tags: texmaker, mactex

I recently upgraded operating system on macbook to macos Sierra and also installed Mactex2016 but Texmaker is not working. Please help me to configure Texmaker with mactex. I tried this [Configure Texmaker with macTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89028/how-to-configure-texmaker-to-work-on-mac-with-mactex) but this did not work.

Comment: Perhaps try uninstalling and reinstalling TeXmaker.

Comment: The expression "Texmaker is not working" is not very specific. *What* isn't working? Does it fail to start up? Does it start up but then fail to execute a compilation run? Please elaborate.

Comment: I tried unistalling and reinstalling Texmaker but still Texmaker not working.

Answer (score 1):

There are some differences between MacTex2016 and previous versions. For instance, you must configure the path for the executable programs using the `/Library/TeX/texbin` folder instead of the previous links in `/usr/texbin`.

Please review the MacTex webpage for this changes: http://www.tug.org/mactex/sierra.html